# Subset of a python list

Tags: python, search, data-structures

I need to find the subset of a python list eg:

```
a = [[1,2,100],[1,3,2100],[2,3,200],[3,4,1600]]
```

lets say that the first element of each element represent start_time and second element is end_time and my query is in the form (start, end). The resulting subset should be such that the start_time and end_time of each element of the subset should be in between start and end.

What is the fastest way to do this (or any structure in which I should save the data to get better running time)?

Comment: And let's ask the most common question, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried temp = [arr for arr in a if arr[0]>=start and arr[1]<=end] but I need something faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *range tree* to store the points. Consider the (start_time, end_time) pair as an (x, y) coordinate. Then querying for (start, end) becomes a matter of finding points in the square [start,end] x [start,end].

Range trees on two dimensions can be computed in O(n log n) time, and queries on them performed in O(log n) time.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any good Python implementations (except possibly [Python Quadtree](http://sgillies.net/blog/275/python-quadtree/)), so you may have to roll your own. However, it will definitely be faster than any linear search solution.

If you don't want to go to the effort of using or writing a range tree, consider using NumPy instead for faster linear searches:

```
arr = np.array(a)
xa, ya, val = arr.T
pts = (xa >= start) & (ya <= end)
print arr[pts]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> start, end = 0, 5
>>> result = [i for i in a if start <= i[0] and end >= i[1]]
>>> print result
... [[1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 2100], [2, 3, 200], [3, 4, 1600]]

>>> start, end = 2, 3
>>> result = [i for i in a if start <= i[0] and end >= i[1]]
>>> print result
... [[2, 3, 200]]
```

list comprehension.  remove the `=` if you want it non-inclusive.

Comment: This searches the full (sorted) list each time.

Comment: I have tried this but it is too slow. The no of elements in the list are in the range of 2000 and I am using dynamic programming ( I select an element from the list and it gives me 2 queries). I need something faster.

Comment: then use bisect, as suggested by @MartijnPieters.

Answer (score 1):

Using the algorithms demonstrated by the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) would give you the fastest search times, but we have to create some sorted indices.

You'd have to store both the start and the endtimes in a list with the index of the entry in the `a` list:

```
starttimes = [(l[0], i) for i,l in enumerate(a)]
starttimes.sort()
endtimes = [(l[1], i) for i, l in enumerate(a)]
endtimes.sort()
```

You then create specialized `bisect` functions based on the `bisect.bisect_left` and `bisect.bisect_right` functions:

```
def bisect_timeseries_start(starttimes, start):
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if starttimes[mid][0] < start: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return starttimes[lo][1]

def bisect_timeseries_end(endtimes, end):
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if end < endtimes[mid][0]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return endtimes[lo][1]
```

Now you can find the start and end indices with these functions:

```
startindex = bisect.bisect_timeseries_start(starttimes, start)
endindex = bisect.bisect_timeseries_end(endtimes, end)
```

Returning your matching range is now easy:

```
startendrange = a[startindex:endindex]
```

Each search has a `O(lg n)` cost, where `n` is the length of the list. It's easy enough to combine these operations into a class encapsulating both the timeseries list `a` and the indices.

Comment: This won't work...the list can't be simultaneously sorted on both the start *and* end times -- it has to be sorted on one key first, then the other (and the other key will therefore not be sorted, making `bisect` invalid).

Comment: You wrote that the list should be sorted. On what basis should it be sorted (there are three elements in each element)??

Comment: @AnkurAnkan: The first two elements, but `a.sort()` will do for your example case.

Comment: @nneonneo: Hrm, you have a point there. So that'd mean you need to create the `endtimes` list and sort that beforehand.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But, then, you can't simply use `a[startindex:endindex]` because the `endtimes` list is out of order.

Comment: @nneonneo: bugger, so it is, updating.